# How to get a specified file extracted from a JAR file using a batch file?

Tags: archiving, 7-zip, jar

I have a test.jar file on windows and I want to use 7-zip to get a certain file from outside of the archive, such as the "com/app/test/FILE.class"  file.   I only have access to java, 7-zip, and the regular DOS utilities from the batch file.  How can I accomplish this?  Should I unzip , search through it, pull it out, then delete the temp files?  What is the best way?   I am unable to find very much info on the 7-zip 'e' command capabilities.

This didnt work:

```
7z.exe -e test.jar -x com\app\test\FILE.class
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract `FILE.class` directly to current directory:

```
7z.exe e test.jar com\app\test\FILE.class
```

To extract file to com\app\text\FILE.class in current directory (folders will be created if they don't exist):

```
7z.exe x test.jar com\app\test\FILE.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `7z.exe e` (without the '-')? According to [the extract command description](http://www.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/commands/extract.htm) you don't need the hyphen.